# Change text colour depending on if condition react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I want to use something similar to `getElementById` in order to select my element and change the text colour. I currently have a unordered list, and wish to change the colour of each individual depending on an if condition.

```
<div style={styles.passwordRules}>
  <ul style={styles.listOne}>
    <li style={styles.li}><span style={styles.error} id="test">8 a 16 caratteri</span></li>
    <li style={styles.li}><span style={styles.fontNormal}>Carattere maiuscolo</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul style={styles.listTwo}>
    <li style={styles.li}><span style={styles.fontNormal}>Un numero</span></li>
    <li style={styles.li}><span style={styles.fontNormal}>Carattere minuscolo</span></li>
  </ul>
  <ul style={styles.listThree}>
    <li style={styles.li}><span style={styles.fontLink}>Nessuna informazione personale</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Meaning that for instance, I would like something similar to this:

```
if(text === 'foo') {
//change colour to grey
}
```

**Please note, I cannot use** `getElementById`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not doing something like this:

```
<li className={text === 'foo' ? styles.class1 : styles.class2 } .../>
```

Answer (score 7):

Branching out from Carl Edwards's answer then if it's only the color you want to change, this should do the trick:

```
<li style={{color: text === "foo" ? "trueColor" : "falseColor"}} ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for example using:

```
<li style={text ==== 'foo' ? _.extend(styles.style, styles.styleFoo) : styles.style }>
```

or if using ES6

```
<li style={text === 'fooo' ? Object.assign({}, styles.style, styles.styleFoo) : styles.style }>
```